# Look for product quantities on a specific res.partner location - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to look for `qty_available` of a product into a specified partner location, I have three `Many2one` fields to `res.partner`,

```
    printer_book_block = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Printer Book Block")
    printer_binding = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Printer Binding")
    printer_edging = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Printer Edging")
```

So, on the lines of this model I should look for those quantities, depending on which `res.partner Many2one` has been selected:

```
    order_lines = fields.One2many('bsi.print.order.lines', 'print_order', string="Order lines")

    @api.multi
    @api.constrains('order_lines', 'order_lines.isbn')
    def check_quantity(self):
        location = self.printer_book_block.property_stock_supplier.id
        for rec in self:
            if rec.order_lines:
                for line in rec.order_lines:
                    if line.qty > line.isbn.qty_available in location:
                        rec.write({'state': 'awaitingraw'})
                    else:
                        rec.write({'state': 'work_in_progress',},)
```

This method should look for `qty_available` on `printer_book_block.property_stock_supplier`, but it seems like it doesn't really look for that particular location.

The field `property_stock_supplier` is a field which is part of `res.partner` model, and it specifies the location for every partner as supplier on the system.

Also, how can I specify if one `res.partner` has been selected to look specifically for it?

Any ideas?

PS = `isbn` is a `Many2one` to `product.product`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell odoo to compute you can specify the location or the warehouse in the context:

```
  if line.qty > line.isbn.with_context({
                     'location' : location, # here id must be an integer not object
                     # 'warehouse': warehouse_id, # integer value 
                }).qty_available >= 0:
```

Comment: Thank You very very much! :)